# Dúvida sobre objetos JS com array

Tags: javascript, array, objetos

Estou com dúvida de como fazer um objeto que tem array dentro, nem sei se isso é possível, mas segue mais ou menos o que eu quero fazer:

```
var produtos =[
    {   nome: "Sei lá",
        cor: azul,
        tamanho: [ M, G, GG] // não sei como faço pra receber uma array aki.
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Criando os produtos

> como fazer um objeto que tem array dentro

É possível criar um objeto dentro de um array sim. Para isso basta utilizar os objetos [**Array**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) e [**Object**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

Exemplo:

```js
/* Cria a constante onde será armazenado os produtos */
const produtos = [];

/* Cria a variável onde será criado o produto */
let produto  = new Object();

/**
  Para criar uma propriedade nesse objeto,
  basta incluir o nome da propriedade na variável do objeto
 */
produto.nome = "Sei lá";
produto.cor = "azul";
produto.isDigital = false;

/* Aqui nós criamos um objeto já setado com um array */
produto.tamanho = ["M", "G", "GG"]

/* Adiciona o produto recém criado na constante produtos */
produtos.push(produto);

console.log( JSON.stringify(produtos) );
```

#### Alterando os produtos

Para alterar esses valore é bem simples, basta acessar o produto através do índice (que vai de 0..n-1), acessar a propriedade e definir um novo valor.

Como a propriedade `tamanho` é um array, nós podemos alterar utilizando o método [**push**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) ou [**unshift**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

```js
produtos = [{
  "nome": "Sei lá",
  "cor": "azul",
  "tamanho": ["M", "G", "GG"]
}]

/**
 * Acessa o primeiro produto e utiliza o método
 * PUSH para inserir um novo valor ao array
 */
produtos[0].tamanho.unshift("P");
produtos[0].tamanho.push("XG");

/* Imprime na tela */
console.log( produtos );
```

#### Lendo as informações

Para ler as informações basta utilizar uma estrutura de repetição como o `for` ou o método `forEach` do objeto `Array`

```js
const produtos = [{
  "nome": "Sei lá",
  "cor": "azul",
  "tamanho": ["M", "G", "GG"]
}]

for (let produto of produtos) {
  console.log( `Produto: ${produto.nome}` );
  console.log( `Produto: ${produto.tamanho[1]}` );
}

console.log( "------------- OU -------------" );

produtos.forEach( produto => {
  console.log( `Produto: ${produto.nome}` );
  console.log( `Produto: ${produto.tamanho[1]}` );
});
```

E caso você queira apenas ler as informações de um produto que tenha determinada característica, basta usar o método `Array.filter`

```js
const produtos = [{
  "nome": "Sei lá",
  "cor": "azul",
  "tamanho": ["M", "G", "GG"]
},{
  "nome": "Sei lá 2",
  "cor": "preto",
  "tamanho": ["PP", "P"]
}]

let produtosFiltrado = produtos.filter( produto => produto.cor == "preto" )

console.log( produtosFiltrado );
```

Comment: Muito obrigada, isso me ajudou até com dúvidas futuras sobre o assunto kkk parabéns!!!